# Out of memory error on orientation change in using fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap

I am having one fragment which as different layout on orientation change. But as I don't want my activity to recreate I have used
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` 
in the Fragment activity which holds my fragment.

So in fragment I am overriding  onConfiguratinoChanged as below :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // need to change the according port/landscape layout file as recreation of activity is restricted.
    main.removeAllViews();        
    main.addView(View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_home, null));
}
```

In `fragment_home` root view I have set the background image which is different for portrait and landscape layouts.

I am setting my background images in the layout xml only.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/tablet_home_main"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bg_landscape" //bg_portrait changed in portrait layout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingTop="10dp" >
```

I have kept my background images in `drawable-hdpi` folder.

This is my fragment :

```
 public class HomeFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    LinearLayout main;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
           ViewGroup container,Bundle   savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,false);
    main = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablet_home_main);     
    return rootView;
     }
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);        
    main.removeAllViews();
    main.addView(View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_home, null));
    }
 }
```

**My issue is when I continuously change the orientation of home fragment 4-5 times my application crashes** and show following error message :

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
```

Comment: are u using Bitmaps(Images) of large size?

Comment: @GopalRao My background bitmap drawable for portait layout is of 51 kb and for landscape layout is 48 kb

Comment: Please show the code where create the bitmap from the stream. You are leaking memory there.

Comment: can you post part of code where you are setting images to ImageView?

Comment: did you add all drawables? e.g. drawable-x-land ,drawable-x

Comment: @WinstonSmith that has nothing to do with this problem. Nads: this is quite a weird issue. This memory should be cleared. Can you post the full fragment code? I think you leak memory somewhere else. I removed my previous answer, which was based on wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

First, in

```
 onCreateView(...)
```

you are inflating view with layout id R.layout.fragment_home and you are assigning this value to main like

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,false);
main = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablet_home_main);
```

so here main is LinearLayout

and in

```
  onConfigurartiion(...)
```

again you are inflating a view with same id R.layout.fragment_home and adding to `main` view.

so you are keep on adding LinearLayout to LinearLayout...

try this..

```
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        frameLayout.addView(view);
        return frameLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        View view = frameLayout.getChildAt(0);
        Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
        frameLayout.removeAllViews();
        if(drawable != null && drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
        }
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landscape_layout, null);
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.portraitlayout, null);
        }
        frameLayout.addView(view);
    }
```

Comment: This could potentially 'fix' the problem, but does not address the actual problem. `removeAllViews()` should clear the memory, but it will not if there are references to the layout or child views. Downvoted since this does not address the underlying issue.

Comment: @JeffreyKlardie be careful when you are downvoting, He is removing Views from Linearlayout means all views in layout are removed. but he is setting background to Linearlayout which is large image. removing all views from linear layout will not clear it's background...

Comment: I removed the downvote as I don't see any clear issues in the fragment that can lead to mem leaks (will remove when I can do that again, time limits). However, `removeAllViews()` is supposed to clear all memory of the deleted views, and therefore doing it yourself is unnecessary. It seems something else is leaking memory.

Comment: @GopalRao But I am restricting  restarting of activity on orientation change, so will it call `onDestroyView()` in fragment

Comment: @JeffreyKlardie child views memory in LinearLayout will be cleared but LinearLayout background will not be cleared...

Comment: I'm an idiot :) You are absolutely right! You should update your answer and describe this issue so it's more clear, if you want.

Comment: @GopalRao it is not calling `onDestroyView()`

Comment: Edit: I can't change the vote anymore unless you make an edit to your answer.

Comment: @GopalRao I tried to recycle bitmap as u suggested in `onConfigurationChanged` method but it throws me different error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap` Please help what should I do.

Comment: @nads are you locking your Activity screen orientation?

Comment: @GopalRao No I havent lock screen orientation. I have just restricted my activity recreation at orientation change.

Comment: @GopalRao as the fragment has different layout respective to orientation,and as I am restricting activity recreation the layouts wont change according So I have relayout the views in the `onConfigurationChanged` method.

Comment: @GopalRao I need to update the layout here as I did ?

Comment: @GopalRao I need to update my layout also on orientation chagne,this updated answer of yours will only update the bacground image only.

Comment: @GopalRao Edited solution was also not working for me. I was giving me `trying to use a recycled bitmap` error. At the end I created only one image for portrait and landscape and also decreased the size of background image. Thanks for all you efforts in helping me.